# Visual Studio Code Terminal Execute Batch on Startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with it's integrated CMD-Window very often - however, I have to execute a specific Batch script right in the beginning before I start to work with the integrated CMD window. Is there any way to do that automatically in Visual Studio Code?